# amsmath: getting an error while using math mode to define piecewise function

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath, cases

I have the following Latex code:

```
\begin{center}
    $\beta(u)$ = \[ \begin{cases}
    1 & $|u_{j}| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ \\
    0 & else
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{center}
```

On the 3rd line, Latex gives me an error: `Missing $ inserted`

And the output I'm getting is:

[image]

I'm not sure how to get rid of the error. Also, how would I make it so that the left hand and right hand side of the equation are on the same line.

Comment: `\[..\]` is display math and is always on its own line. You can't put anything ahead of it expecting it would appear on the same line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `center` environment and use (`amsmath` has to be loaded):

```
 \[ \beta(u)=\begin{cases}
1 & |u_{j}| \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases} \]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the error rises because you are including an equation environment `$ $` inside another `\[ \]`.

Using `amsmath`'s `equation*` makes the code cleaner in my opinion.

```
\begin{equation*}
    \beta(u) = \begin{cases}
    1 & |u_{j}| \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
    0 & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```